# Keeping database table clean using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework and I have a table that I use to record some events that gets generated by a 3rd party. These events are valid for 3 days. So I like to clean out any events that is older than 3 days to keep my database table leaner. Is there anyway I can do this? Some approach that won't cause any performance issue during clean up.

Comment: Which Db server you are using ?

Comment: Currently I am doing my dev using a localDb but will deploy in the future to Azure SQL database.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Agent job which runs everyday at night or at the least peak time and it cleans your data . So also the overhead will be away from your application server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the mentioned above there are some options :

1) Define stored procedure mapped to your EF . And you can use Quarts Trigger to execute this method using timely manner.

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net

2) SQL Server Agent job which runs every day at the least peak time and remove your rows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

If only the method required for cleaning purpose nothing else i recommend you go with option 2

Comment: Thanks Hany. I have already got Quartz configured in my solution. However, I couldn't find the SQL server Agent. Its probably because of my management studio version. However, for now I am going to just set an schedule and use my EF to get all records and delete the old ones. To start with I don't expect to have more than a few thousand rows in any 3 days, which should be ok for EF and my web app but longer term I have to visit this page again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all. Make sure the 3rd party write a timestamp on every record, in that way you will be able to track how old the record is.

then. Create a script that deletes all record that are older than 3 days.

DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),thatColumn) < -3

now create a scheduled task in SQL management Studio:

In SQL Management Studio, navigate to the server, then expand the SQL Server Agent item, and finally the Jobs folder to view, edit, add scheduled jobs.

set script to run once every day or whatever please you :)

Comment: Thanks David. I couldn't find the agent, possibly due to the version of the studio. I am planning to use Quartz scheduler and EF for going live as I don't expect much traffic and probably visit this in a few months or years. :) Thanks again.